# How to wrap Marionette view without div?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to create a composite view to build a table with each table row as a child view. I want to have two table rows in each childview. Marionette composite view is wrapping my child view in empty div which I dont want. How do I achieve this? I know that I can use "id" attribute for the view and render the table row  with `<tr>`, but in this case I have two 'tr' entries in childView.

HTML tempate :

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/html">
  <tr>
      <td><%= product %></td>
      <td><%= price %></td>
      <td><%= discount %></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="secret"><%= hiddenCode %></td>
   </tr>
</script>

<script id="table-template" type="text/html">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Laptop Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myData = [{product: "Dell", price: "500$", discount: "30%", hiddenCode: "OFFER20"},
             {product: "Acer", price: "400$", discount: "50%", hiddenCode: "OFFER70"},
             {product: "Apple", price: "2020$", discount: "10%", hiddenCode: "NoOFFER"},
             {product: "HP", price: "700$", discount: "30%", hiddenCode: "FREE"},
             {product: "Lenevo", price: "200$", discount: "40%", hiddenCode: "NoOFFER"}];
var RowCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
var rowCollection = new RowCollection(myData);
var RowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#row-template"
});

var TableView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  childView: RowView,
  childViewContainer: "tbody",
  template: "#table-template"
});

var tableView = new TableView({collection: rowCollection });
tableView.render();
$("#result").html(tableView.el);
console.log(tableView.el);
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sreekanth67/8v3n9tfz/

Answer (score 0):

you can define `tagName: table` for the CompositeView. See Backbone docs [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View) for reference.

```
var RowView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: 'tr',
  template: "#row-template"
});
```